# Event sourcing, hold read side consistent

Tags: event-sourcing

I'm new in ES, and only trying to sort everything in my head. I have heard that ES is actually solving the consistency issue between write and read database (with some delay for sure). But I still do not fully understand how?

If command is coming to domain and aggregate root firing event to update event store, same event is sending to update read side?? But what if message lost, we will have outdated read side.

Is `projections` the only solution??So instead of updating from event, read side walking through event store and reproducing aggregate (from beginning or from some snapshot). But in such case it's probably breaking some rules as read side should be simple and it should not know about domain. And also usually read side is a separate application so she can't know about aggregate.

For sure we also can use `rabbitMQ` or some other message broker to not lost messages,and actually I think we need. But I also read that to make it consistent "you can use rabbit or ES", but again how ES can make it consistent by own??

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Benjamin is completely right about the purpose of Event Sourcing.

My answer aims to add some more details.

**First:**

Read models and projections aren't suppose to represent the aggregate state.

Projections are the way for event-sourced systems to build the read model for CQRS. CQRS in essence postulates that write and read models usually serve different purposes and therefore it makes perfect sense to use another model for the read side.

Therefore, you often find multiple projections building different, narrowly purposed models, targeting specific needs for queries.

**Second:**

By "solving consistency issues" you probably mean that in event-sourced systems each state transition is represented as an event (or multiple events). Therefore, writes are always transactional. The database you choose as your event store should support (could using some library or additional tool) real-time subscription that would allow you to receive new events in your projection, *in order*. For new projections, it will start reading from the start and eventually come real-time. Subscriptions usually need to keep the current processing position in the global stream of events so when the projection restarts, it starts receiving events from the point which is last known to it.

By doing this, you will guarantee that every state transition in the write model will be reflected in the read model. This is probably what you mean in your original question.

**Third:**

Now, all those things above imply that you cannot use a message bus (only) to deliver events to projections. Brokers give no ordering guarantees and can deliver one message more than once. Also, message brokers don't keep history so you cannot build new projections at will.

However, it doesn't mean that you can't use brokers at all. Some projections don't require ordering and are idempotent. But the feed for events to publish via a broker is the same subscription, so you get guaranteed delivery and can read past events if necessary.

**Fourth:**

CQRS doesn't imply separate databases. Sometimes, using CQRS just means that you use some persistence layer for your domain objects, so you read and write aggregates. But for queries, you just query at will, whatever you want. A database view is a technical example of CQRS.

**Almost there:**

Projections need to have little to no logic, it is true. The main point here is to ensure idempotency, if possible, so projections usually should not use operations to calculate new values based on old values and information from events.

But projections will know about your domain. Everything in your system should know about your domain.

**And last:**

You can definitely use different databases for write and read models without getting to Event Sourcing. You just need to choose a database that supports a change feed. SQL Server, Postgres, CosmosDb and other databases have such functionality.

P.S. I'd suggest spending some time studying those concepts. I can point to the book repository, it has CQRS and Event Sourcing examples: https://github.com/PacktPublishing/Hands-On-Domain-Driven-Design-with-.NET-Core

Comment: In case of postgersql https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/sql-notify.html this is a change feed functionality you talking about? Is it guaranty the "message" delivery?? I never use that functionality before. Thank you for such a greate answer

Comment: And can I also use it to fire events to other microservices (not projections), or in such case better to use message brokers? Also in case of postgres notify you need to write triggers and it's probably means moving part of the logic to the database which on my opinion not very good and clear solution.

Comment: Well, I wouldn't expose domain events to other services as integration messages. Unless a set of microservices belong to the same bounded context, using domain events for integration induces coupling. I would subscribe to the event stream, do a conversion from domain events to integration events and use a broker. A broker is perfect for integration.

Answer (score 2):

> I have heard that ES is actually solving the consistency issue between
>   write and read database

To the best of my knowledge, Event sourcing has NOTHING to do with consistency between read/write to your db. Consistency between read/write has actually more to do with the type of db you are using such as relational which are mostly ACID versus the non-relational db which are often eventual consistency.

ES is not meant for that, instead ES : "Capture all changes to an application state as a sequence of events" [Martin Fowler](https://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/EventSourcing.html).

ES works like time machine, which allows you to change the state of your application to a specific date time in the past.

Comment: Well, but CQRS also have nothing to do with consistency, it's just a separation of ead/write operations, it's not even strictly  require to use separate Db's. But in most cases with ES, you need to have separate read DB, as event store querying is not trivial task